# making an API that adds instances to ManyToMany fields of a model in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am making a movie watching website in which there are users and films and the user model has a ManyToMany Field that references the film model. it's called WatchList and an authenticated user can add any movie they want to this watchlist.

My problem is that I want an API that only gets the ID of a film and adds it to the user's watch list.

these are my models and serializers and I am trying to make a view to implement this API.

```
# models.py
class Film(models.Model):
    filmID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    # ...

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    userID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex="^(?=[a-z0-9._]{5,20}$)(?!.*[_.]{2})[^_.].*[^_.]$")])
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True,  validators=[EmailValidator()])
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    watchList = models.ManyToManyField(Film)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```

```
# serializers.py
class WatchListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        model = Film
        fields = ('filmID', 'title',)
        read_only_fields = ('filmID', 'title')

    film_set = FilmSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('userID', 'film_set')
        read_only_fields = ('userID',)
```

```
# views.py
class WatchListAddView(...):
    pass
```

The serializer can be changed. but this kind of shows what I want the api to be. the authentication validation part is already taken care of, so imagine that any request to the view is from an authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend patching this directly and instead create a separate endpoint for adding removing data to this field.

In your case it would look like this. I show just a small working example, you can adjust it to your needs

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    @action(detail=True,
            methods=['POST'])
    def add_film_to_watch_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        film = get_object_or_404(klass=Film, filmID=kwargs.get('filmID'))
        user = self.get_object()
        user.watchList.add(film)
        return Response("Success")
```

Comment: could you direct me to any tutorial or documentation on how I could create "a separate endpoint" for this issue?

Comment: Sure, here is documentation for @action decorator - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions